# Why do I get a "ConnectionString property has not been initialized" error on the first call to a stored procedure with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a service in ASP.NET Core to which I inject my Entity Framework Core context that is used to define a private func that my service will need.
That func is about calling a stored procedure.

The first call to that func systematically leads to an error

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

However, subsequent calls are fine.

Here is the service class constructor:

```
private readonly Func<Task<long>> _myFunc;

public MyService(MyContext context) => _myFunc= async () =>
    {
        using (var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection())
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "sp_MyStoredProcedure";
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AParameter", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 1 });
                return (long)await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
            }
        }
    };
```

Here is the `stacktrace`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

UPDATE:

When I set a breakpoint on line `await connection.OpenAsync()` and look at the variable `connection` the connection string is there and correct.

Note that `MyServices` is injected into a controller constructor.
The service registration is done this way in `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

Comment: I'd look at the GetDbConnection method. Where is the connection defined for it?

Comment: Maybe you need to provide the connection object (if the type is DbConnection) into your `command.Connection = connection;` before opening the `await connection.OpenAsync()`

Comment: @user1443098 `GetDbConnection` returns the connection of the database of the context which is injected and properly setup.

Comment: @Max `connection.CreateCommand` surely links the `command` and the `connection` already.

Comment: The problem must lies inside your GetDbConnection method as @user1443098 suggested. You need to check if the object connection contains the ConnectionString

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @François  OK. where would you look for the connection string injection?

Comment: I'll look and revert but if the connection from GetDbConnection doesn't have the connection string the first time I don't see why it would have it for the next calls.

Comment: It's not clear here how `_myFunc` is being utilized. I'd imagine you're mishandling the asynchronous stuff (not awaiting properly, etc.) and since the context is scoped, your code is likely running with indeterministic state.

Comment: I'm properly awaiting. Issue surely lies on the scope as you say.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 7):

Try not to disposing of the connection as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10911844/532575.

So, basically, replace `using (var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection())` with `var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection()` and see whether it helps.