# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized executing for second time asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I facing a strange problem, when I execute the code below for second time I got an exception

this method exists inside DB context (entity framework core)

Code:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(string spname, params object[] ps)
{
    string json = string.Empty;
    using (var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)this.Database.GetDbConnection())
    {
        var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = spname;
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        for (int i = 0; i < ps.Length; i++)
        {
            var obj = ps[i];
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo nameprop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("name");
            string name = (string)(nameprop.GetValue(obj, null));

            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo valprop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("value");
            dynamic val = (dynamic)(valprop.GetValue(obj, null));

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(name, val));
        }
        this.Database.OpenConnection();
        using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var rawdata = Serialize(result);
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rawdata, Formatting.Indented);
        }
    }
    
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(json);
}
```

Exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'
```

Comment: Why would you not [let EntityFramework do the work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)? It will be much more efficient than converting between json and back again, and much less error prone

Comment: Very similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10911635/5803406

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson because EF Core cannot execute a stored procedure that does not related to dbset

Comment: @devNull actually yes, I did not pay attention 
but i have added a dynamic execute stored procedure inside EF Core that dose not related to dbset and it's full dynamic

Comment: @IssaSaman do you know which stored procedures are available at compile time, or is that dynamic as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by remove using

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(string spname, params object[] ps)
{
    string json = string.Empty;
    var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)this.Database.GetDbConnection();
    var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = spname;
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    for (int i = 0; i < ps.Length; i++)
    {
        var obj = ps[i];
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo nameprop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("name");
        string name = (string)(nameprop.GetValue(obj, null));


        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo valprop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("value");
        dynamic val = (dynamic)(valprop.GetValue(obj, null));

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(name, val));
    }
    this.Database.OpenConnection();
    var result = command.ExecuteReader();
    var rawdata = Serialize(result);
    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rawdata, Formatting.Indented);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(json);
}
```

When you leave your "using" block, .NET runtime will call the Dispose() method of the variable for you. So by the second time the method is called, your static connection variable is no longer valid.

Try remove the using statement from your method and you'll be fine.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ae6780da-7ad6-4e90-977e-7b0a71345be8/the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized-random-error?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: it's wrong to remove using. you need to use using block to prevent cpu and memory high usage. try to use sqlConnection.Open() instead of this.Database.OpenConnection().

Comment: @Asherguru i tried what you are saying ,, to be noted it's one connection and same context so there is no high usage

Comment: you will get high usage when there are many users using your website at the same time like 5000+ users unless you have injected dependency. i have experienced it before and i also used one connection and same context. i just inform you so that you won't make same mistake as me.

Comment: @Asherguru can you explain more please 
and by i used dependency injection for this

Comment: oh, you have used dependency injection. then yours will be fine.